# How to get sum of records from two tables in one record when column has values and seperate records when column having null for same number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having two tables .Data from two tables look like this

[image]

Scenario:

1. when column STATUS is available in any one of the tables or both table then sum the total AMT for the particular account number and fetch the highest date for the account number.
2. When column STATUS is null each row should display as it is.

Expected result:

[image]

I have tried and got the following result for not null cases in status column but i am not able to get the records for null values.

```
SELECT ACNO, SUM(AMT), MAX(DT) FROM (
SELECT ACNO, MAX(due_date) DT, SUM(AMT) AMT 
FROM PDC
WHERE NVL (STATUS, 'K') IN ('Z','C')
GROUP BY ACNO
UNION ALL
SELECT ACNO, MAX(due_date) DT, SUM(AMT) AMT
FROM OVD WHERE NVL (STATUS, 'K') IN ('D') GROUP BY ACNO)
GROUP BY ACNO ;
```

Below are the query table and data

```
    create table pdc (
    acno varchar2(10),
    amt number,
    due_date date,
    status varchar2(2)
);


create table ovd (
    acno varchar2(10),
    amt number,
    due_date date,
    status varchar2(2)
);

insert into pdc values ('100',1000,to_date('01-jan-2023','dd-mon-yyyy'),'Z');
insert into pdc values ('100',1000,to_date('01-FEB-2023','dd-mon-yyyy'),'C');
insert into ovd values ('100',1000,to_date('01-mar-2023','dd-mon-yyyy'),'D');
insert into ovd values ('200',1000,to_date('01-apr-2023','dd-mon-yyyy'),'D');
insert into ovd values ('100',1000,to_date('01-may-2023','dd-mon-yyyy'),null);
insert into ovd values ('100',1000,to_date('01-jun-2023','dd-mon-yyyy'),null);
insert into pdc values ('100',1000,to_date('01-JUL-2023','dd-mon-yyyy'),NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"WHERE NVL (STATUS, 'K') IN ('Z','C')" will always remove entries where STATUS is null, because 'K' is never in ('Z', 'C').

This should give you the result you wanted by adding two more queries at the end for the entries with status null:

```
SELECT ACNO, SUM(AMT), MAX(DT) FROM (
  SELECT ACNO, MAX(due_date) DT, SUM(AMT) AMT 
  FROM PDC
  WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY ACNO
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ACNO, MAX(due_date) DT, SUM(AMT) AMT
  FROM OVD WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ACNO)
GROUP BY ACNO 
UNION ALL
SELECT ACNO, AMT, due_date as DT 
FROM PDC
WHERE STATUS IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ACNO, AMT, due_date as DT
FROM OVD WHERE STATUS IS NULL;
```

This will only check if the status is null or not though. If there are certain statuses that should not be grouped you would have to replace the "NOT NULL" phrase again.

Answer (score 1):

You could UNION your data and transform Null STATUS values into anything unique per ACNO (I used your DUE_DATE column - it could be anything else) AND transform your existing STATUS values into something fixed and same (I put 'STATUS'). After that it is a simple aggregation grouped by ACNO and (transformed) STATUS.

```sql
Select   ACNO, Max(DUE_DATE) "DUE_DATE", Sum(AMT) "AMT"
From    (   Select ACNO, AMT, DUE_DATE, Case When STATUS Is Null Then To_Char(DUE_DATE, 'yymmdd') Else 'STATUS' End "STATUS" From PDC Union All
            Select ACNO, AMT, DUE_DATE, Case When STATUS Is Null Then To_Char(DUE_DATE, 'yymmdd') Else 'STATUS' End "STATUS" From OVD  )
Group By ACNO, STATUS
Order By DUE_DATE
--  R e s u l t
--  ACNO       DUE_DATE         AMT
--  ---------- --------- ----------
--  100        01-MAR-23       3000
--  200        01-APR-23       1000
--  100        01-MAY-23       1000
--  100        01-JUN-23       1000
--  100        01-JUL-23       1000
```